# No puedo poner la direccion de un archivo en un File de Java( MAC )

Tags: java, jlayer

desde ayer he querido usar el .jar jlayer para reproducir música mp3 en Netbeans, todo va bien pero cuando intento utilizar la dirección de el archivo mp3 me marca error(OJO estoy en MAC) no importa que haga el try-catch me marca que no existe esa carpeta por favor podrian ayudarme.

Esta es la direccion que siempre pongo en el File y no da:
"‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩/⁨Usuarios⁩/⁨imabsolutions-biondi⁩/⁨Escritorio⁩/Kana-Boon - Silhouette.mp3"

[image: ACA EL CODIGO]

Comment: Hola, bienvenido al sitio. Como sugerencia, debes colocar el código con el cual estas trabajando. Date una vuelta por el sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y aprende cómo postear una pregunta y así obtener mayor respuesta a tus dudas. Sin el código es difícil entender cuál es el problema en específico.

Comment: Podrías subir algo de código?? Ahí podríamos ver donde puede estar el error y partir desde ahí para solucionar el problema.

Comment: por favor ayuda

Comment: Sugerencia: coloca el código. No pongas una captura.

Answer (score 0):

El problema puede ser en en método AbrirFichero. Le estás pasando una ruta que no corresponde.

En vez de `cd desktop/Kana-Boon - Silhouette.mp3` **copia la dirección del archivo** y coloca esa dirección en AbrirFichero. La manera en que colocas la dirección (Macintosh HD⁩/⁨Usuarios⁩/⁨imabsolutions-biondi⁩/⁨Escritorio⁩/Kana-Boon - Silhouette.mp3) no es la correcta. Debería ser similar a directorios Linux.

Tendrías algo como esto:

```
try{
        Principal mi_reproductor = new Principal();
        mi_reproductor.AbrirFichero("/home/usuario/Documentos/archivo.mp3");
        mi_reproductor.Play();
      } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
      }
```

Es obvio que /home/usuario/Documentos/archivo.mp3 no es tu ruta, es un ejemplo.

Comment: muchas gracias no sabia como poner las rutas en mac

Comment: solo puse la que yo ponia en el terminal